# "Vault","Consul" and "Terraform" [ Hashicorp products] cannot be opened because the developer can not be verified issue on mac, Catalina

Tags: macos, terraform, consul, macos-catalina, hashicorp-vault

Have tried to add Hashicorp tools on mac and facing this error
[image]

any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Have tried these solutions and could solve it:

1. run this command:

   `sudo spctl --master-disable to allow apps downloaded from anywhere`
2. Go to 
        System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General and enable any blocked app from Allow apps downloaded from pane at the bottom of
   the window.

Comment: this solution allowed me to sidestep the issue as well for a vault 1.2.3 client on a recently upgraded catalina 10.15.3

Comment: Thank you, I encountered the same issue and it fixed mine using the first command :)

Answer (score 1):

Terraform's [0.12.18 release notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.12.18) mentions this:

> cli: Our darwin releases for this version and up will be signed and notarized according to Apple's requirements.
>
> Prior to this release, MacOS 10.15+ users attemping to run our software [reported](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23033) seeing the error: "'terraform' cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified." This error affected all MacOS 10.15+ users who downloaded our software directly via web browsers, and was caused by [changes to Apple's third-party software requirements](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04102019a).
>
> [Our recommended approach to install and interact with the Terraform CLI can be found here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/install).
>
> MacOS 10.15+ users should plan to upgrade to 0.12.18+.